# Can universities require computer science students to develop software for free?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, software, ownership, education

At my university (it is a public Florida university), one of the core computer science courses required for the degree involves a group project, and the class is divided up into a dozen or so teams, each with their own project.  This is fairly common.

The questionable thing is this: local companies each pay the department a few thousand dollars to have the students develop their software for them, since it is cheaper than hiring professionals.  The students, who are paying tuition, don't get a cut of this money.
While this can be an ethical debate (they are getting experience, but they are paying to work for free, etc.), I would like to know about the legality of this.

Comment: I think it is important for an answer to consider public vs private universities

Comment: Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/48484/who-are-the-copyright-holders-of-softwares-that-students-develop-during-their-st

Comment: Comment only, since different legislation: in Germany, this would not be legal. The professor *forcing* students to licence their work to the university would run foul of anti-corruption legislation (https://www.tu-braunschweig.de/fileadmin/Redaktionsgruppen/Stabsstellen/Datenschutz/Gesetze_und_Regelungen/messer-helmut-rechtsgrundsaetze-zu-diplomarbeiten-vortrag-2005-11-10.pdf) (and the licensing "contract" would be void due to abuse of power). The university selling services cheaper than market price would at least raise questions about state-aid legislation (and maybe unfair competition).

Comment: Has any student attempted to attach a copyright notice to their submission forbidding reproduction, for any purpose other than grading, or any derivative work?

Comment: Such arrangements are not uncommon in US higher education, and you can bet the whole thing has been carefully scrutinized by the university's lawyers, who I will venture to say have thought about it much harder than anyone on this website.  If this were not legal, it's unlikely it'd still exist.

Comment: I think there are at least three separate issues to analyze: (1) may the university require work on a company's project as a condition for graduation; (2) who owns the intellectual property; (3) does it violate minimum wage laws to have the students do the work without getting paid.  The answers below have addressed (2), and sort of (1), but not (3).

Comment: @NateEldredge it's probably not directly analogous, but it does smack a bit of the relationship between unpaid college athletes and the moneymaking machines for which they play.  There's increasing sentiment that this amounts to exploitation, so perhaps someone challenging an arrangement like this could somehow benefit from that sentiment.

Comment: @phoog: To me, the closest analogy is unpaid internships, where a student does work for a company in exchange for academic credit.  There is [an established test](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/whd/fact-sheets/71-flsa-internships) for the legality of such internships with respect to minimum wage law.  Most of the factors seem to be met here; I think the main one at issue is #6: "The extent to which the intern’s work complements, rather than displaces, the work of paid employees while providing significant educational benefits to the intern." [...]

Comment: But in fact such projects are usually things that the company would find interesting or beneficial in some way, but not interesting enough to pay employees regular wages to do it; so that it doesn't tend to displace paid employees.  And the university faculty will typically sign off that they consider the project as providing significant educational benefits.

Comment: @NateEldredge In making their decision, the uni's lawyers would apply significant weight to the (un)likelihood that the students will question the arrangement (let alone challenge it in court). The actual (il)legality of the arrangement weights very little.

Comment: @NateEldredge: It sounds like the sort of University which would have this vetted by their law students, not by real lawyers.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the agreement between the parties.

In analyzing the debate between @Moo and @Greendrake in the comments to the answer by @Greendrake, it's clear that any contract between the parties will control. And in the absence of any agreement to the contrary, the student owns the copyright.

Controlling agreements could include any tuition agreement, scholarship grants, admissions, enrollment or application agreement at the university level and, at the course level, a simple waiver would be sufficient to assign intellectual property rights.

@Greendrake seems to be arguing no IP assignment is valid unless it is accompanied by a standalone payment from the university to the student. That is an incorrect interpretation of contract law. In this case, the entirety of the contract, including the education services provided by the university, would serve as sufficient consideration for the contract to be binding on both parties. Evidence of the sufficiency of consideration would be the agreement itself and the behavior of the parties, including the payment of any tuition by the student.

Comment: But the education services provided by the university are already provided in consideration for tuition charges.  If that account is settled, how can they also be consideration for labor provided by the students?

Comment: @phoog: Your comment begs the question and assumes its conclusion with your qualification: "if that account is settled." That's the point of my answer. In other words, does the tuition settle the account or does it not? It depends on the agreement between the parties. I handle the case you are assuming in the last sentence of paragraph two: "in the absence of any agreement to the contrary, the student owns the copyright."

Comment: @phoog: There are plenty of situations where the student has to pay consideration beyond their regular tuition in order to take a particular course; lab fees, field trip costs, etc.  This would typically be stated as part of the basic agreement with the student.  So the group project course could be another example of the same, but here, the additional consideration to be provided is the student's assignment of the IP rights.

Comment: @phoog: In other words, you seem to be assuming that the university, in exchange for the base tuition payment, promised the student the right to take all possible courses without additional consideration.  I don't think that was ever the deal.

Comment: Ever heard of illusory consideration? See my answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

The university certainly can, as part of its study programme, require students to develop software (for free).

However, as the students are not *hired* to write the software, [they own the copyright](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/48484/who-are-the-copyright-holders-of-softwares-that-students-develop-during-their-st).

The university violates that copyright by selling the software to third parties.

The students can legally require the university to stop doing that, or to agree to pay them a % of the revenue.

One can argue that transferring the copyright / IP to the university could be part of the student's consideration (on top of any tuition fees they pay). The problem with this is that, whilst the students have to produce software to get a pass mark, they do not have to do it contract-wise: the university won't have a legal stand to sue the students for damages should they not deliver the software. Yes they will fail the course but they will still fulfil their contract obligations. Therefore, the software/IP "consideration" here is [illusory](http://www.sixstjameshall.com.au/news/2018/6/29/illusory-consideration-and-uncertain-terms-arguments-of-last-resort). An illusory consideration is not good one, hence it is not part of the contract.

Comment: There may be a copyright grant or assignment to the university in the tuition agreement, so this answer isnt as blanket as it sounds.

Comment: @Moo That "assignment" would have been void unless the students are paid (which they are not).

Comment: And where do you believe that from?  Copyright grants or assignments are a common thing, especially in opensource software development (note I said common, not the norm) where there is no payment (if you want your code in the master branch, you assign copyright to the owner if the project), and it seems to have withstood the test of time there.

Comment: @Moo I trust the linked answer from user6726 on that. Also, granting/assigning copyright like that won't be enforceable unless there is a consideration on the grantee side (yes I do doubt very much such assignment is enforceable in opensource too). Tuition can hardly be seen as consideration as students (or the state) pay for it separately, and the delivery of tuition does not depend on the delivery of the students' software: they may fail the course if not developed the software, but they will still get their tuition.

Comment: The Free Software Foundation and Gnu (and their lawyers) seem perfectly happy requiring it, so Im happy standing by my comments.

Comment: @Moo I'd need to see case law proving this answer wrong. Lawyers are only happy until judges make them not.

Comment: Cisco seemed to think its valid and settled rather than argue that the copyright assignment wasn't lawful - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Software_Foundation,_Inc._v._Cisco_Systems,_Inc.

Comment: @Greendrake the students have to receive consideration - not necessarily payment. Their education is good consideration.

Comment: @DaleM I wouldn't expect a uni to _necessarily_ expect students to produce software worth a cent. I also wouldn't expect a reasonable entity to agree to deliver its consideration (e.g. education) in return for something it knows may not (and often will not) worth a cent. Rather, the uni opportunistically takes advantage of the students (if lucky) — on top of what students (or their sponsors e.g. state) _must_ deliver — payment for education. This makes the software no valid part of the students' consideration, and hence no part of a contract.

Comment: If an instructor validates the end product for fitness of purpose, do they not act as the final author?  A student's submission can only act as a draft, can it not?  Because a student, who is not a party to the contract, can't be held responsible.  And, as the final author (employed by the University), isn't the instructor providing work for hire?  An interesting question would be whether a student can attach to their submission a copyright notice forbidding reproduction (for any purpose other than grading) or any derivative work.  Would such a notice carry any weight?

Comment: It would carry the same weight as various posts on Facebook saying "I hereby declare that no organisation has any right to use my data for advertising or tracking". Unilateral alterations to a contract are not enforceable (except in specific circumstances that are usually defined explicitly by law). That is to say, it carries no weight at all. @grovkin the instructor is not an author at all, the student is, for the purpose of moral rights, and discussion of student work as "work for hire" is entirely the wrong tree to bark up.

Comment: @Nij you make a few statements without any supporting evidence and one statement which is not relevant here at all.  I didn't engage in any discussion of students' work being work-for-hire.  I stated that the course instructor, as a university employee, is providing work for hire.  I am curious why you think that placing a comment inside a submitted take-home project amounts to an alteration of a contract.  A student would not take away a university's ability to judge their performance (because that use of the project would be allowed in the copyright statement).

Comment: @Nij the whole bit about who is the author of the work passed to the university's clients also needs some support.  You are just stating it without any evidence.  Do you expect the people on this site to take this as informative because it's stated assertively?  The stated purpose of this site is "for education purposes."  I don't see how one assertive commentator can be educational without providing references.

Comment: If it doesn't change the contract, it isn't necessary to include such a statement, because the contract would be clear that work cannot be used for other purposes outside assesment. If it would change the contract, it's pointless, because unilateral changes are not enforceable (and this is a basic tenet of contract law, asking for a reference is like expecting citations for "2×7=14"). The course instructor can be providing ownership of the moon, it still wouldn't make them the author of anything they didn't actually write (and this is a statement of fact, *author* is a word with a meaning).

Comment: @Nij suppose the course instructor runs the code through a filter which removes all the comments from the code and changes the names of all the functions and variables. Would that be substantive enough to change the authorship? What if they additionally run it through a filter which automatically refactors the code by pulling large code blocks into separate functions? Would the student still retain authorship? To muddy the waters even further, consider that all academic scientific publications put the head of the lab as the last author in the list of paper's authors (even if they did nothing).

Comment: Academic standards for authorship are tangential to legal standards for authorship. They are very barely based on similar principles, vary enormously, and can be totally ignored when a publisher wants without legal effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106809/discussion-between-grovkin-and-nij).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106857/discussion-on-answer-by-greendrake-can-universities-require-computer-science-stu).

Comment: @grovkin If you were correct, the professor would be violating copyright law by creating a derivative work (the final product) without permissions of the copyright holder of the original works (the students). And even so, the only work for hire would be the specific elements of protectable expression the professor added themselves. Any protectable elements authored by the students and remaining in the final work would still belong to them, meaning their consent would be needed to distribute it. (Else a professor could make his own cut of The Phantom Menace as a WfH and the uni would own it.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the question of what distinguishes derivative work from copying (with minor modifications) revolves around how substantive the changes are.  Ulysses, for example, is not considered a derivative work of the Odyssey.  While I agree that the 1st two modifications, to which I alluded, would probably be derivative, I am not sure about the last one.  Having a program effectively re-write (re-factor) a piece of code can produce a piece of code which is substantively different.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't know if the fact that the code interacts similarly with the environment (produces same audio/visual results, implements identical protocols, etc.) is what matters. If the question is whether it would compile into sufficiently similar program on the binary level, then it can be (automatically) refactored enough to not produce a similar program on the binary level.

Comment: @grovkin There is no conceivable way this could work. Think through the analogy with a movie instead of a computer program. Think of the student's work as The Phantom Menace. The professor can't even take the conceptual elements like the characters and setting, much less the actual video or dialog. It's precisely the same with software. He couldn't take any protectable elements the students authored because if he did, anyone who distributed the final work would need the students' permission to distribute the protectable expression they authored.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I understand the analogy to a movie.  But what about the fact that the code implementing many algorithms looks essentially the same?  In fact, an experienced developer can often look at large swaths of code and know exactly what it does without thinking it through because a lot of code is just repetitive implementation of the same patterns (in fact there is an industry term "Design Patterns").

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Given the limited time any one student has during a semester, it's likely that only a medium-to-large group can implement a working project.  And each student would only only do a small, easily identifiable part.  This isn't even like a scene from a movie.  The amount of work one student would do would be about as much as setting up a camera and moving it forward and backwards, and maybe a few times to the sides, in a movie.

Comment: @grovkin You can make that same argument about a movie or video game that has hundreds of authors. It won't work. Honestly, it's a frivolous argument. Sure, the professor could extract the *ideas* from the students' code and re-implement them, but even that would be dangerous as the distinction between what is an idea and what is an element of protectable expression is a tricky legal question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I believe my argument is that there are very few original ideas in most code.  In fact, you probably would not be surprised to find out that quite a bit of it is copy-n-past from stackoverflow.  The most difficult part of software development is finding the time to put it all down in writing.  There are likely few, or even no, ideas that a student contributes which a professor does not already know.   The slightly original part is in putting it all together.  But presumably, that's what the instructor would do.  I don't disagree with your premise, maybe the facts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106906/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-grovkin).